# How do I change the permissions of a system file on every login?

Tags: permissions, chmod

I need to make a system file writable without using sudo so I typed:

```
sudo chmod 646 /path/to/file
```

It worked…

…until I rebooted, because the file is recreated on every boot.

How do I change the file permissions on every boot?

Comment: What file are you changing permission on and why ?

Comment: It's the brightness level file in /sys. I need to enable changing the value by the user due to problems with brightness control since the upgrade to 13.04.

Answer (score 1):

it should be enough:

`# echo "chmod 646 /path/to/file" >> /etc/rc.local`

Comment: Depends on the file. That command may run too early in the boot process and there is likely a better method to configure the problem.

Comment: Adding the line to `/etc/rc.local` worked but not by using the command above. This line needs to be *before* the last line (exit).